# How to remove duplicate names of routes when testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-mvc-test

I have a simple controller REST:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository repository;

    @GetMapping("")
    List<Employee> all() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    Employee one(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return repository
                .findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EmployeeNotFoundException(id));
    }
}
```

Further I write a test for this controller.

```
public class EmployeeControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void all() throws Exception {
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/employees"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].name", is("John")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[0].role", is("admin")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].id", is(2)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].name", is("Mike")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$[1].role", is("user")));
    }

    @Test
    public void one() throws Exception {
        int id = 1;

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/employees/{id}", id))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("id", is(1)))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("name", is("John")))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("role", is("admin")));
    }
}
```

But the problem is that there is too much duplication of the name of the route "/employees".
And if there are requirements to change the name of the route, I will have to change a hundred tests. Very bad.

Also how to eliminate duplication when using the base route and the parameter, here while only one parameter: {id}.
But there may also be requirements to change the name of the parameter.

Please tell how you organize the code and eliminate duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to introduce a

`public static final String PATH = "/employees";` variable in `EmployeeController` so you can reference the "/employees" path anywhere

Comment: We cannot add this variable to annotation. So need to duplicate string in controller, isn't it?

Comment: You can use this variable in the annotation because it's final. Just use it like `@RequestMapping(EmployeeController.PATH)`

Comment: Hell, I did not include class name... :-(

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
EmployeeController.class.getAnnotation(RequestMapping.class).value()[0];
```

to get path from controller's @RequestMapping("/employees")

> "/employees"